# Android Studio - Save TextView value for different users

Tags: android

My application has an authentication service made in .net and SSMS(SQL Server)

In one of my activities, I want to store a TextView value (that is incrementing due to the user using the application) so that each user has his own value. For example, user 1 uses the application 1h and closes the application. If user 2 logins in the app, the value should be different. When user 1 logins again, the value should be the last one before he closes the app.

Which method should I use in this case? Should I use SharedPreferences?

**EDIT 08/09/2020**

> UserPoints.java

```
public class UserPoints extends AppCompatActivity{

    private TextView userMoneyTV;
    private BroadcastReceiver minuteUpdateReceiver;
    private int userMoney = 0;

    private Button saveMoney, loadMoney;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_points);

        userMoneyTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userMoney);

        final String UserMoney = userMoneyTV.getText().toString();



        saveMoney = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveMoney);
        saveMoney.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS",MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("money", UserMoney);
                editor.putString("email", String.valueOf(R.id.email));
                editor.commit();
            }
        });

        loadMoney = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadMoney);
        loadMoney.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS",MODE_PRIVATE);
                String money = preferences.getString("money",UserMoney);
                String email = preferences.getString("email",String.valueOf(R.id.email));
                userMoneyTV.setText(money);
            }
        });

    }

    public void startMinuteUpdateReceiver(){
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);

        minuteUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                userMoney++;
                userMoneyTV.setText(""+ userMoney);
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(minuteUpdateReceiver,intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startMinuteUpdateReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(minuteUpdateReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

> activity_user_points.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rewardLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rewardInfoLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/chestReward"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:src="@drawable/chestreward"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rewardText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chestReward"
            android:text="Earn money every minute you use the app"
            android:layout_marginTop="175dp">

        </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/moneyInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rewardInfoLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userMoneyText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="casual"
            android:text="Your Money: "></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userMoney"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/userMoneyText"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/euro"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="€"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/userMoney"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/moneyInfo">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveMoney"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save Money"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:onClick="startVideoAd">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loadMoney"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Load Money"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/saveMoney">
        </Button>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT 9/9/2020**

My problem was solved with **EDIT 8/9/2020**

Now my question is, how can i make the value increasing when i'm in another activity? AsyncTask?

Comment: Maybe SQLite? You can save every login-logout time. Based on this You can calculate how much time the user spends using the app and also in the future You can add some "features" like `time in last week` or `time after midnight` etc.

Comment: The value is some kind of fake money for the user, you know? User 1 uses the app and gets a amount. I  want to store that amount so then when the user logins again that value remains the last one and don't reset to 0

Comment: The value increases by 1, each minute User uses the app

Comment: So maybe keep it in the SQL server, for user_table add a new column `money` and keep money there. You don't have to update SQL every minute. Just read data when the user opens the app and then write new data when the user closes the app.

Comment: How can i read the data when user opens the app and write new data when user closes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `SharedPreferences` but if the user uninstalls the application user will lose its data and the value you've stored in `SharedPreferences`.
And if you want to save data even after uninstalling the app you can use any lightweight database i.e. `Realm`,`Room`,`SQLite`,`Firebase` and store your local database in users sd card. Else use Google backup service or store it in another place like on your server.

Comment: That it is not the problem, since it is a fictitious value. SharedPreferences will differentiate the users?

Comment: Yes, just in shared preferences as a key use user-id. It will differentiate users.

Comment: Can you please show me a example? I don't know how sharedpreferences will differentiate users since i don't have any "user-id" attribute in my User model

Comment: yeah as @iknow said it will work and make sure you don't clear SharedPreferences while logout the user and if you want too then store this particular value in different SharedPreferences class so you can get back even after logout and new or previous user login.

Comment: I've updated my question. Can you please check it out?